# How to get my bot to join a voice channel

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to get my discord bot to connect to a voice channel like this currently:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
message.content = message.content.lower()
if message.author == client.user:
    return

if '-skip' in message.content:
    await message.author.channel.connect
    await message.channel.send (f"-p scotland forever")
    await disconnect
```

Basically I want it to join a voice channel from the message author when they send the message "-skip" and then my bot joins, says -p scotland forever in chat, and then leaves. I get an error message saying things like "channel" not defined or "connect" not defined, ive tried doing it a few different ways, I think i just havent imported a plugin or whatever and thats probably my issue, but idk what plugin thing to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might find this [example](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/ab667b74e9758433b3eb806c53a19f34#gistcomment-3341314) helpful on how to get a basic music bot up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if '-skip' in message.content:
        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        if channel is not None:
            await channel.connect()
            await message.channel.send (f"-p scotland forever")
            await client.voice_clients[0].disconnect()
        else:
            await message.channel.send ("You need to join to voice channel")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@commands.command()
async def join_voice(self, ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice
    if connected:
        await connected.channel.connect(put vc id here)
```

It may work
I guess?

Comment: The question is using `message.content`, not `commands.command()`, therefore your answer would not apply to this question despite this being a valid working solution.